# Selecting multiple answers from input in an array

Tags: python

I would like to know how to do this.

```
yesAnswer = ["yes","ya","Yes"]

start = input("Would you like to start?[Yes or No]")

if start == yesAnswer:
    print("Awesome! Let's roll!")
else:
    print("Alrighty then. Bye bye.")
```

I tried that however it does not refer to the variable...

What is an alternative?

Comment: Thank you all! I appreciate the fast replies and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wanna check if something is in a list, use `in`, not `==`, like so:

```
if start in yesAnswer:
    print("Awesome! Let's roll!")
else:
    print("Alrighty then. Bye bye.")
```

Comment: Awesome. Seriously appreciate it. I wasn't quite sure what to look for so this definitely cleared everything up. Do you have any recommended python courses or books I can read?

Comment: @swift if you like videos there are programming courses that use python at iTunes U's Stanford  and MIT pages and there's a neat course at udacity.com. There's a course called Learn Python the Hard Way that a lot of people like but I'm not a huge fan. I've never read a python book so I can't really give you my opinion on those. I've learned mostly by doing and googling.  There are some nice suggestions here: http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-start-learning-Python

Comment: @swift also, ozgur's suggestion to use `.lower()` is a good one, it decreases the number of variations you have to include in yesAnswer

Comment: Oh I see that. That helps me very much! Thanks again for the help. I will check those out.

Answer (score 3):

Use `in` to check for membership. Besides, you can use `.lower()` to eliminate the check for both `yes` and `Yes` (or `YES` too):

```
>>> yesAnswer = ["yes", "ya"]
>>> start = input("Would you like to start?[Yes or No]")

>>> if start.lower() in yesAnswer:
...     print("Awesome! Let's roll!")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
yesAnswer = ["yes","ya","Yes"]

start = input("Would you like to start?[Yes or No]")

if start in yesAnswer:
    print("Awesome! Let's roll!")
else:
    print("Alrighty then. Bye bye.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the **in** keyword.

```
if start in yesAnswer:
```